# Draw good circle with SDL that is not as pixelated

Tags: c, algorithm, drawing, sdl-2

I want to draw a circle.

This is my code and my output (`SDL_SetRenderDrawHexColor` is my own function that gives hex and converts that to rgba and `SDL_SetRenderDrawColor`.)

[image: vscode ide]

Why is my output some pixely? I use this algorithm in canvas(js) and that was good, but in SDL it's bad. I think pixels are big, is that true?

(For some reason I can't use `SDL_gfx`.)

Comment: Quick guess: `SDL_RenderDrawPoint` draws a pixel at integer coordinates. The HTML canvas takes floating-point coordinates and anti-aliases the output according to the fractional part. That means lines will look smoother in the canvas in general. (Sometimes the rendering will look blurry, though.) I guess you could replicate the behaviour in the canvas if you snap your coordinates to integer values.

Comment: i using ```var putpixel = (x,y) => context.fillRect(x,y,1,1);``` so it anti-aliases?

Comment: Well, I said "a quick guess".

Comment: Please don't paste your code as a image - it is not searchable, nor copyable - should somebody answering the question want to copy it or use in an answer

Comment: Why did you tag this question with C++ when your title says the C language?  They are distinct languages.  The C language can use identifiers "class" and "namespace".  The C++ language has `std::string` and `std::vector`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The arguments to trigonometric functions such as `SDL_Cos()` are in radians and a floating point type (a `double` in this case). You are passing them in degrees, as integers.

By looping over the angle (the range should be `0 <= i < 2 * pi`) you will draw more points than are needed for small radius circles and a discontinuous line for larger ones.  Because `sin(x)` and `cos(x)` are periodic functions, using degrees rather than radians means you still move round the circle, but not in the way you wanted.

The [Midpoint circle algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midpoint_circle_algorithm) is one way to do this correctly.  This exploits symmetry to only calculate points in one `1/8th` of circumference and then project them round to the other 8 ways.

I concur with other answers that you probably have sub-pixel antialiasing (more strictly, it's down oversampled, then downsampled with a low-pass filter) in HTML canvas.  This is a very different proposition to drawing concentric rings with a gradient as you are attempting here.

Answer (score -1):

I propose an implementation of the algorithm to draw a circle that draws 8 points (one for each octant) at a time, without using the trigonometric functions; the Rad parameter of type int is the radius of the circle in pixels; the parameters CX and CY of type int are the coordinates of the center of the circle; the color I chose to represent the circle is black.

Setting CX = 250, CY = 250, Rad = 200 this is the result (since the image I can insert here is quite small, I have created a square of 500x500 pixels, and the coordinates of the center are identical, but I have also successfully performed 1 test with CX = 640, CY = 400, Rad = 350 on a rectangular image):

[image]

```
int SqrRad=Rad*Rad;
int X=0;
int Y;

SDL_SetRenderDrawHexColor(ren, 0xffffffff);
SDL_RenderClear(ren);

SDL_SetRenderDrawHexColor(ren,0x000000ff);

do {Y=sqrt(SqrRad-X*X);
    SDL_RenderDrawPoint(ren,CX-X,CY-Y);
    SDL_RenderDrawPoint(ren,CX+X,CY-Y);
    SDL_RenderDrawPoint(ren,CX-X,CY+Y);
    SDL_RenderDrawPoint(ren,CX+X,CY+Y);
    SDL_RenderDrawPoint(ren,CX-Y,CY-X); /* Swapped CX with CY */
    SDL_RenderDrawPoint(ren,CX-Y,CY+X);
    SDL_RenderDrawPoint(ren,CX+Y,CY-X);
    SDL_RenderDrawPoint(ren,CX+Y,CY+X);} while (X++>=Y);
```

NOTE: I substituted renderer with ren and removed the old bad followed source-code.

Comment: My program works: the circumference of the circle has no holes, since with the formula Y = R ^ 2-X ^ 2, if X starts from 0 and is increasing, when X <= Y, the values of Y are contiguous.